# How to run rqt_graph in ROS2?

Tags: ros2, ros-crystal, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have seen rqt_visualization and found that rqt_graph is already ported for the Crystal. I have run rqt_graph by `rosrun rqt_graph rqt_graph` command in ROS1 (melodic) but don't know about Crystal.

I have tried `ros2 run rqt_graph rqt_graph` after building on crystal and source setup.bash but not able to run.

Please provide me guidance for the same.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/314475/how-to-run-rqt_graph-in-ros2?/) by [Gabbar](https://answers.ros.org/users/38969/gabbar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2019-02-01

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-02-04**:
Assuming you have built the latest state from the `crystal-devel` branch in the `rqt_graph` repo have you tried to call just `rqt_graph`?

**Comment by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) on 2019-02-04**:
Cool, I missed that last update.
Do you plan to release a stable version in a patch for crystal or will it be only in D-turtle?

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2019-02-04**:
That depends on the feedback on https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_graph/pull/22#issuecomment-460307808

**Comment by [Gabbar](https://answers.ros.org/users/38969/gabbar/) on 2019-02-04**:
@Dirk Thomas
Yes, I have tried `rqt_graph` command and it is opening one window like rqt and rqt_plot but specifically for rqt_graph. So, We can access the rqt graph with `rqt_graph` command with arguments.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rqt_graph` has been released for Crystal and will be in the main repo with the next sync. It can be invoked standalone by just calling `rqt_graph` on the command line.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2019-02-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4